Problems with os.rename | OSError: [WinError 123]
I'm looking to rename one of my files using os.rename, the code is a little bit messy but currently it gives me a result that looks like it should work, but I end up getting an error. (path is removed but it is not actually removed in the code)
Snippet of my code:
mxk='''"'''
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
m = root.clipboard_get() #all clipboard functions working 
bb=r"\blank.pdf"
cc=mxk
nd = (m[:40]+bb+cc)
print(m,nd)
os.rename(m, nd)

Print response: (m, nd)
"C:\l-final_words.pdf" "C:\blank.pdf"

Error:
 File "C:\main.py", line 179, in <module>
    os.rename(m, nd)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:\\l-final_words.pdf"' -> '"C:\\Ublank.pdf"'

Does anybody have any suggestions fixing this code?

Why are you appending literal double-quote characters to the filename? Get rid of the mxk stuff.

It also looks like you're copying the double-quote characters into the clipboard. Don't do that.

Quotes are needed when you're typing some filenames into the command prompt. They're not used when calling an API.

The reason I'm adding a double quote at the end is because if I don't the print response will be missing an end quote and not be a valid path

Paths don't need quotes to be valid. You're confusing the path with the shell syntax.

So what it sounds like you're saying @Barmar is that I won't need the quote characters when using them to reference path in a cmd, the problem is the method that I'm using to copy the path is directly from the files and it comes with quotes around it, do I need to remove those quotes in the m variable? and if so, do I need to remove the quotes in the nd variable as well?

Yes, you need to remove the quotes. They're needed in cmd, but not in os.rename() (or any other functions in Python).

So I removed the mxk function and the +cc but I'm still getting a print response of: "C:\lbnl_secj_app_b_m134.pdf" "C:\blank.pdf
the second var still has an opening quote
does that mean I have to do some weird text alter thing to the m variable first to remove the quotes before bring them to nm?

Looks like you didn't remove the quotes from m.

Since it is copied directly from the files, it comes with quotes so I can't really do that in code, maybe I can copy paste it into notepad or something and remove the quotes that way or something but I can't do it directly from the code, at least not to the extent of my knowledge, which, to be fair, is limited

You shouldn't have explicit quotes around the filenames.
Also, use os.path functions to merge a filename with the directory of the original file, rather than string slicing with a magic number.
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
m = root.clipboard_get().strip('"') #all clipboard functions working 
bb=r"blank.pdf"
nd = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(m), bb)
print(m,nd)
os.rename(m, nd)

